# Median value resulting in negative number

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, data-analysis, median

I know the that the formula for finding the median of grouped data that is:

$$\mathrm{Median} = L_m + \left [ \frac { \frac{n}{2} - F_{m-1} }{f_m} \right ] \times c$$

And I also know what the letters stand for. So I decided to create some mock data:

```
 x             f.             cf.

 1-5           100            100
 6-10          340            440
 11-15         10             450
 16-20         34             484
 21-25         12             496
```

And tried to find the median value :

$$\mathrm{Median} = 11 + \left [ \frac { \frac{25}{2} - 440 }{10} \right ] \times 5$$

According to this formula, my median value is coming to `-202.75`, which looks pretty wrong. What am I missing here?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood both what $L_m$ and $n$ refer to. $n$ is the total number of samples (so 496 in this case) and $L_m$ is the minimum of the group in which the $n/2$-th point occurs - so the 6-10 group.

Comment: It seems that I have indeed misunderstood the variables, thank you for clarifying that @Sten. The site I was referring to for help (mathsisfun.com/data/frequency-grouped-mean-median-mode.html) is extremely unclear about what is what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\mathrm{Median} = L_m + \frac{n/2 -cf_b}{f_m}*w
$$

here
$L_m$ = median group where the median lies in

$n$ = total number of data

$cf_b$ = culm. freq before the median group

$f_m$ = frequency of median group

$w$ = width of groups

So for your problem:

$L_m$ = (6)-10,$n$ = 496, $cf_b$ = 100, $f_m$ = 340 and $w$ = 5

This leads to:

$$
\mathrm{Median} = 6 + \frac{496/2-100}{340}5 = 6 + \frac{148*5}{340} = 6 + 2.176 \approx 8.18
$$

So the error was choosing the right numbers for the formula, especially where the median lies.

Comment: Thank you for the edits :). I hope the answer provides some extra help.